# Slim 3 + Pleague 2.4 - Alias (router) is not being managed by the container?

Tags: ioc-container, slim-3, thephpleague

How do I use [Pleague](http://container.thephpleague.com/2.x/getting-started/)v2.4 with [Slim](https://www.slimframework.com/) v3.8.1?

Following this [example](https://jenssegers.com/73/dependency-injection-with-league-s-new-container), I tried:

```
// PSR 7 standard.
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;

// Import classes.
use Slim\App as Slim;

use League\Container\Container;
$container = new Container;

// Required to enable auto wiring.
$container->delegate(
    new \League\Container\ReflectionContainer
);

// Get an instance of Slim.
$app = new Slim($container);
```

I get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught League\Container\Exception\NotFoundException:
>   Alias (router) is not being managed by the container in
>   /var/www/html/projectA/vendor/league/container/src/Container.php:266
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/projectA/vendor/league/container/src/Container.php(93):
>   League\Container\Container->getFromDelegate('router', Array) #1
>   /var/www/html/projectA/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(239):
>   League\Container\Container->get('router') #2
>   /var/www/html/projectA/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(143):
>   Slim\App->map(Array, '/', Object(Closure)) #3
>   /var/www/html/projectA/public/index.php(53): Slim\App->get('/',
>   Object(Closure)) #4 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/html/projectA/vendor/league/container/src/Container.php on
>   line 266

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slim is trying to access the `router` which isn't defined on the container you've added. In Slim they will be added by the [`\Slim\DefaultServicesProvider`](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/DefaultServicesProvider.php).
But you cannot use it because your DI Container doesn't support array access.

An option to fix this problem is to set the Slim container as delegate, then the `League\Container\Container` will get the router and all other stuff through the slim container:

```php
$container = new \League\Container\Container;
$container->delegate(new \Slim\Container());
$app = new \Slim\App($container);
```